# Is Google Wallet API will allow multiple recipients during a single transaction

Tags: android-pay

I am implementing Google Wallet API integration with PHP website. Seems there is no way to add multiple recipients during a single transaction. please let me know if there is any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably needs some clarification from OP so subject to that clarification:

- Google Wallet for Digital and/or Instant Buy, yes, there is only *one payer* (the Google Wallet account/user who will *pay*)
- *recipient* however seems to be up to you/your app, more so with Instant Buy since control of the transaction/order flow is handed back to you/your web site. Google (Instant Buy) just handles part of the payment flow (not the entire order/transaction process)

Hth